# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el valor se muestre en verde al ser positivo y en rojo cuando es negativo?

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando hacer un panel de inversión y me encuentro con problema para conseguir que el texto se muestre en verde cuando es positivo y el texto se muestre en rojo cuando es negativo.
Me refiero al valor percentual en este caso, el de 1.30883%
He probado esto pero nada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código escrito:

```
JavaScript:
if(Math.sign(stockOnePercentChange.textContent) === 1) {
stockOnePercentChange.textContent.style.color = "green"
}

HTML: 
<div class="stock1percentchange"></div>

CSS: 
.stock1percentchange {
 margin-left: 2vh;
}
```

(Hay más CSS heredado pero son solo cosas tipo margen y eso, no es necesario saberlo)

Comment: ¿Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar ese código como texto en lugar de imagen?  Si queremos ayudarte nos obligas a reescribirlo para nuestras pruebas y somos perezosos por naturaleza :-)  De paso agrega el HTML y el CSS actual correspondiente a ese elemento, para tener el contexto completo y hacer de ello un [example].

Comment: ¿Qué significa *he probado esto, pero __nada__*? ¿Algún error en consola? ¿Cuándo y cómo ejecutas ese código? Por otro lado el código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Haz clic en [edit] y corrige tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: A ver, varias cosas a corregir antes de aplicar mi respuesta. 1) No dices que es el objeto **stockOnePercentChange** en el javascript.. ¿ a que corresponde? 2) Si eso va a ser una clase entonces debes usar **getElementsByClassName** para almacenar todos los elementos que la usan en una variable 3) Luego debes utilizar un bucle para recorrer los valores de esa variable y **aplicar el código corregido con el condicional** que ya tienes, agregándole un **else** para los casos en rojo, y yasta

Answer (score 2):

Te sobra el `textContent`. El estilo se aplica sobre el elemento, no sobre texto puro. Ponlo así:

```
if(Math.sign(stockOnePercentChange.textContent) === 1) {
  stockOnePercentChange.style.color = "green"
} else {
  stockOnePercentChange.style.color = "red"
}
```

Aquí tienes un snippet con todo lo comentado en la pregunta que te faltaba:

```js
stockOnePercentChange = document.getElementsByClassName('stock1percentchange')
for (i = 0; i < stockOnePercentChange.length; i++) {
  if(Math.sign(stockOnePercentChange[i].textContent) === 1) {
    stockOnePercentChange[i].style.color = "green"
  } else {
    stockOnePercentChange[i].style.color = "red"
  }
}
```

```css
.stock1percentchange {
  margin-left: 2vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="stock1percentchange">1</div>
<div class="stock1percentchange">-1</div>
```